# Why can't I set maxwidth in Android WebView onLayout?

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-layout, android-webview

I'm trying to override the onLayout of a WebView, to restrict size of large images to the screen size. In my overridden WebView, I tried:

```
@Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        Log.d("WEBVIEW-WIDTH",""+getWidth());
        post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                loadUrl("javascript:var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');"+
                         "for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {imgs[i].style.maxwidth='"+getWidth()+"'};");
            }
        });

    }
```

When rotated, it logs the new width, but doesn't restrict the width of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't working because I used maxwidth, not maxWidth.

Fortunately, it looks like there is a much better way to display it, which updates the image size when zooming and rotating:

```
 img { max-width: 100%; }
```

From http://davidwalsh.name/image-max-width